# Receive Push Notification in background and create a local Notification without the user knowledge

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving a remote push notification, and i need to register a UILocalNotification, within 30 minutes, but i need to do it even if the user do not click in the notification, in the background.

There's any way to do it, like in :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

}
```

It works fine here, but only if the user clicks in the notification, or if the app is currently running.

Comment: Why don't send an another push notification after 30 minutes?

Comment: Because i need to start to count after the user receives the notification, he have 30 minutes to answer the request @AttilaH

Answer (score 2):

You can't handle a remote notification if the application is not running until the user doesn't launch your app. You should deal with the business logic on server-side. Keep track of when the notifications are sent and trigger the appropriate action after the time frame are exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on "background fetch" in the "capabilities" section of your project settings, and use the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` delegate method in your `ApplicationDelegate` file. This way you can handle remote notifications in the background. Don't forget to set the content-available flag in your `aps` dictionary when sending the push.